# Scraping one column from a HTML table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know there n number of questions on BeautifulSoup but after trying a few things I am unable to figure out how to parse the data I need from this HTML table.

My table looks like this:

```
<table class="W(100%) M(0)" data-test="historical-prices" data-reactid="33">
    <thead data-reactid="34">
        <tr class="C($tertiaryColor) Fz(xs) Ta(end)" data-reactid="35">
            <th class="Ta(start) W(100px) Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="36"><span data-reactid="37">Date</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="38"><span data-reactid="39">Open</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="40"><span data-reactid="41">High</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="42"><span data-reactid="43">Low</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="44"><span data-reactid="45">Close*</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="46"><span data-reactid="47">Adj Close**</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="48"><span data-reactid="49">Volume</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-reactid="50">
        <tr class="BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)" data-reactid="51">
            <td class="Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)" data-reactid="52"><span data-reactid="53">Oct 10, 2019</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="54"><span data-reactid="55">2,918.55</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="56"><span data-reactid="57">2,948.46</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="58"><span data-reactid="59">2,917.12</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="60"><span data-reactid="61">2,938.13</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="62"><span data-reactid="63">2,938.13</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="64"><span data-reactid="65">3,217,250,000</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)" data-reactid="66">
            <td class="Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)" data-reactid="67"><span data-reactid="68">Oct 09, 2019</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="69"><span data-reactid="70">2,911.10</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="71"><span data-reactid="72">2,929.32</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="73"><span data-reactid="74">2,907.41</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="75"><span data-reactid="76">2,919.40</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="77"><span data-reactid="78">2,919.40</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="79"><span data-reactid="80">2,726,820,000</span></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I want to extract the data from the column "**Adj Close**".
The problem I am having is that all `<td>` class attributes have the same value.

How do I just extract all the data in the "**Adj Close**" column?

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_html = simple_get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?p=%5EGSPC')
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", attrs={'class':'W(100%) M(0)'})
stock_history_list=[]

try:
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        print(cols)
        if len(cols) > 0:
            stock_history_list.append(cols[5].text.strip())
except: pass  

stock_history_array = np.asarray(stock_history_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(stock_history_array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the HTML into a list of dictionaries for quick lookup:

```
header, *data = [[i.text for i in b.find_all('th' if not b.td else 'td')] for b in d.find_all('tr')]
result = [dict(zip(header, i)) for i in data]
vals = [i['Adj Close**'] for i in result]
```

Or, using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
vals = df['Adj Close**']
```

Output:

```
0    2,938.13
1    2,919.40
Name: Adj Close**, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-of-type (If you know index then specify direct or I show how to get it based on headers). Using bs4 4.7.1+

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<table class="W(100%) M(0)" data-test="historical-prices" data-reactid="33">
    <thead data-reactid="34">
        <tr class="C($tertiaryColor) Fz(xs) Ta(end)" data-reactid="35">
            <th class="Ta(start) W(100px) Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="36"><span data-reactid="37">Date</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="38"><span data-reactid="39">Open</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="40"><span data-reactid="41">High</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="42"><span data-reactid="43">Low</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="44"><span data-reactid="45">Close*</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="46"><span data-reactid="47">Adj Close**</span></th>
            <th class="Fw(400) Py(6px)" data-reactid="48"><span data-reactid="49">Volume</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-reactid="50">
        <tr class="BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)" data-reactid="51">
            <td class="Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)" data-reactid="52"><span data-reactid="53">Oct 10, 2019</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="54"><span data-reactid="55">2,918.55</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="56"><span data-reactid="57">2,948.46</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="58"><span data-reactid="59">2,917.12</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="60"><span data-reactid="61">2,938.13</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="62"><span data-reactid="63">2,938.13</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="64"><span data-reactid="65">3,217,250,000</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)" data-reactid="66">
            <td class="Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)" data-reactid="67"><span data-reactid="68">Oct 09, 2019</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="69"><span data-reactid="70">2,911.10</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="71"><span data-reactid="72">2,929.32</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="73"><span data-reactid="74">2,907.41</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="75"><span data-reactid="76">2,919.40</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="77"><span data-reactid="78">2,919.40</span></td>
            <td class="Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" data-reactid="79"><span data-reactid="80">2,726,820,000</span></td>
        </tr>
</table>'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
index = [th.text for th in soup.select('[data-test="historical-prices"] th')].index('Adj Close**') + 1
data = [td.text for td in soup.select(f'[data-test="historical-prices"] td:nth-of-type({index})')]
print(data)
```